# Move embedded CSS to a separate CSS file

Tags: css

I want to remove the following from an html page and add it to an existing css sheet. Do I have to do anything special like creating a new `.mynewclass` or simply remove the `<style>` tags?

```
<style>
    <!--
    .rightAlign
    {
       text-align:right;
    }

    .leftPad05em
    {
       padding-left:0.5em;
    }

    .bottomPad05em
    {
       padding-bottom:0.5em;
    }

    .topPad05em
    {
       padding-top:0.5em;
    }

    .topBottomPad1em
    {
       padding:1em 0em 1em 0em;
    }

    .bottomControl
    {
       padding-left:14.5em;
    }
    -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add your styles to a external stylesheet for example - `default.css`

Include these in that stylesheet -

```
.leftPad05em { padding-left:0.5em; }
.bottomPad05em { padding-bottom:0.5em; }
.topPad05em { padding-top:0.5em; }
.topBottomPad1em { padding:1em 0em 1em 0em; }
.bottomControl { padding-left:14.5em; }
```

and in your `header` include this -

`<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

This is calling the `default.css` style sheet. *Note*, `href="value"` would be where the style sheet is located

Comment: Thank you for taking out time for helping others :)

Answer (score 1):

If the existing CSS file is already imported in the HTML, then moving the inline CSS from the HTML to the file should work.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it sufficient to write the embedding css code in your CSS file. Check if the classes already exist. If so, add the CSS atributes to these classes otherwise paste the code into the file.